# git lfs "Object does not exist on the server"

Tags: git, git-lfs

We've got a git repo which uses lfs for large file tracking. We've been using it for quite a while and it's going ok. However, we have 3 objects which are referenced in a commit but haven't been uploaded to the server. I've tried to get everyone to do a full push of all of their lfs objects, but it's tough to get everyone who has had anything to do with the repo to do this.

Is there anything we can do to avoid this error?

Alternatively, how can I find out which file it is pointing to and which commit so that I can more intelligently figure out who is responsible and get them to push all their files from their machine (if they still have it)?